# When is this even possible (even for a dense graphs) $|E| = \Theta (|V|^2)$

Tags: graphs, asymptotics

Wikipedia says that "a dense graph is a graph in which the number of edges is close to the maximal number of edges."  and "The maximum number of edges for an undirected graph is $|V|(|V|-1)/2$".  Then why do even use $ |E| = \Theta (|V|^2)$?, understand that $\Theta$ is the correct(tightest) bound in asymptomatic notation.  It seems to me that $|E| = \Theta (|V|^2)$ can never happen, so why do we use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that asymptotic bounds only apply to *infinite sequences*.

In this case, $|E| = \Theta(|V|^2)$ applies to an implicit infinite sequence of graphs $G_i=(V_i,E_i)$, meaning that there are two positive constants $c,c'$ such that, $c\cdot|V_i|^2 \leq |E_i| \leq c'\cdot|V_i|^2$ whenever $i$ is large enough.

This constraint can be satisfied. For every $i\in \mathbb N$, take $G_i$ to be the complete graph on $\{1,\ldots, i\}$. Hence, $G_i$ has exactly $i\cdot(i-1)/2$ edges. For large enough $i$, we have
$$
\frac{1}{4}i^2 \leq \frac{i\cdot(i-1)}{2} \leq \frac{1}{2}i^2
$$
So, we can say that $|E| = \Theta(|V|^2)$.

Another sequence could be constructed taking "almost complete" graphs, where we remove one edge from each complete graph $G_i$ in the previous sequence. This would still satisfy the bound.

We could even remove, say, $100*i$ edges from each $G_i$ (when possible) and still satisfy the bound. This is because we only care about $|E_i|$ growing with "quadratic speed".

Comment: Balanced complete bipartite graphs $K_{\lceil n/2\rceil,\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$ (with about $n^2/4$ edges) are a good example to show that there are dense graphs that aren't just "cliques with a few edges removed".

Answer (score 3):

You're absolutely right that $\Theta$ is the tightest asymptotic bound. But it's still asymptotic, and that means that we don't care about constant factors or terms of lower degree: when $n$ (or $v$ or whatever) gets big enough, the smaller terms become negligible.

In this case, $\frac{v(v-1)}{2} = \frac{1}{2} v^2 + \frac{-1}{2} v$. So removing the constant factors and lower terms leaves us with $v^2$.

Comment: I don't understand your last paragraph. It doesn't make sense to use $\Theta$ on a single graph anyway, since there's nothing to go to infinity. But $\Theta$ absolutely includes a lower bound.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Sorry, let me rephrase: using $\Theta$ implies that you can put a lower bound on how many edges are in a graph, in terms of the number of vertices. But the lower bound is always zero. So I would use $O$, which is only concerned with the upper bound (and it is in fact bounded above in terms of the number of vertices).

Comment: But asymptotic bounds don't apply to single graphs. We need to be talking about _classes_ of graphs being dense and, in that case, we absolutely need to use $\Theta$ because it's precisely the lower-bound that defines density. If we just said "A class of graphs is dense if the $n$-vertex members of the class have $O(n^2)$ edges", then every class would be dense.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Ahh, I see what you mean, I misread the question. I thought they were saying the number of edges in a general simple undirected graph was $\Theta(n^2)$ (not specifically in a dense graph), which makes no sense because there isn't a lower bound there.